# Reading .txt file in Python from OneDrive using Office365 API

Tags: python, office365, onedrive

I wish to read a text file stored in OneDrive using Python. I have an Office 365 subscription. I used the following code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
username, password = "<username>", "<password>" #Fields replaced by placeholders
site_url = 'https://<company>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<email_id>/'
file_url = 'Documents/textfile.txt'
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
    print(response)
    info = str(response.content)
    print(info)
```

But running this leads to an HTTP bad request:

```
<Response [400]>
b'{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"serverRelativeUrl\\r\\nParameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter."}}}'
```

Searching on StackOverflow, I found that the relative URL in `File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)` must begin with `/` for accessing SharePoint files through Python, but if I use `file_url = '/Documents/textfile.txt'` for OneDrive, a bad request is raised with an error message:

```
<Response [400]>
b'{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"}}}'
```

However, I can read text files stored in SharePoint hassle-free:

```
site_url = 'https://<company>.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/'
file_url = '/sites/sitename/Shared Documents/myfile.txt'
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(file_url, ctx_auth)
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
    print(response)
    info = str(response.content).replace('b', '').replace('\'', '')
    print(info)
```

Output

```
<Response [200]>
Hello World!
```

Also, I face no problem in reading Excel files stored in OneDrive as Pandas dataframes.

What could I be doing wrong in reading text files from OneDrive?